# Did Merin and Siri set off Siri's Rebellion together following Siri's death?

Tags: hyperion-cantos

What are the supporting events leading up to Siri's Rebellion, and how was the rebellion set off?

I recall the Consul's origin story towards the end of the first book in which Merin, his grandfather, visited Siri's tomb and read her diary. There was an explosion which destroyed the farcaster shortly thereafter. Was this this event which triggered the rebellion?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was. Because by blowing up the farcaster he cut off the immediate link to the Web, meaning the Hegemony had to wait 11 more years to take control of the planet